# Get elements from one list based on another boolean list

Tags: python

I have two lists of the same size, one is a list of strings, and the other a list of booleans (`True`, `False`) and I want to return a list of strings only if the index is True.

```
b_list = [True, False, True]
s_list = ['abc', 'sfsfsfsf', 'def']
```

want

```
s_list = ['abc','def']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`itertools.compress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress)

> *compress(data, selectors)*: Return *data* elements corresponding to true *selectors* elements

So `s_list` is *data* and `b_list` is *selectors*:

```
In [8]: import itertools

In [9]: list(itertools.compress(s_list, b_list))
Out[9]: ['abc', 'def']
```

Answer (score 2):

Without `itertools` using list comprehension:

```
[y for (x,y) in zip(b_list, s_list) if x]
```